# Functional Programming scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I was following "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" from coursera and in the second week the assignments is about "Purely Functional Sets"
We have,

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

and followed by some functions like

```
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (element: Int) => s(element) || t(element)
```

So, when I do,

```
val u = union(Set(1, 2, 3), Set(4, 5, 6))
```

in scala console, it gives

```
u: Set = <\function1\>
```

***a)*** why is it returning a function?

***b)*** when I do `contains(u, 6)` it returns true but can I display all elements in u or because u is a function I cannot?

***c)*** How does `union(Set(1, 2, 3), Set(4, 5, 6))` return all elements  in those two sets without any iteration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a) why is it returning a function?

Because `Set` is a function. `Int => Boolean` means "a function taking an `Int` and returning a `Boolean`."

> b) when I do `contains(u,6)` it returns true but can I display all elements in u or because u is a function I cannot?

You cannot display all elements because a `Set` doesn't actually "contain" elements. A `Set` is a function of one or more tests returning true/false.

> c) How does `union(Set(1,2,3),Set(4,5,6))` return all elements in those two sets without any iteration?

The only way to know what values return true from a given `Set` is to pass in all possible values (or some accepted approximation). Values in the `Set` will return **true** otherwise you get **false**.

Note: This only applies to `Set` as defined in the question. The `Set` found in the Scala Standard Library is a different animal.

Comment: How can Set be a data structure and a function at the same time?

Comment: It might depend on how you define "data structure." Some could argue that `Set`, the function, **is** a kind of data structure simply because it acts like one, but most people expect a data structure to take up more memory with every element it contains and the function `Set` doesn't do that. Here's a `Set` of all the negative integers: `val neg:Set=_<0` As I mentioned, the Standard Library `Set` is different. That is a proper data structure. The Coursera `Set` is designed to help students get used to handling functions as "first class citizens," i.e. passed around like data.

Answer (score -3):

no doubt this is complicated business. Let's see how it goes.
Now I did this:

```
  type Sett = Int => Boolean

  def union(s: Sett, t: Sett): Sett = 
    (element: Int) => s(element) || t(element)

  val x = Set(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[Sett]
  val y = Set(4, 5, 6).asInstanceOf[Sett]
  val u = union(x, y)

  def contains(s: Sett, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)

  println(contains(u, 6))
```

**Notice I am using Sett! Not Set**. The Set above is actually scala.collections.immutable.Set. Sett is my own custom 'type'. The type is defined as Int => Boolean i.e. a function type which takes Int as parameter and returns a boolean. I renamed the custom type to Sett to avoid the confusion that one is my type, and other belongs to Scala library.
Another thing I have highlighted in my code above is, I am casting Scala's Set to my Sett! This cast works! How does it work? This is due to the fact that immutable Set inherits from Function1.. so works great.. this comment is thanks to Jorge below
The Scala Set is actually Set[Int], since it is Set(1,2,3) etc. So it is perfectly legit to cast it to subclass Sett which conforms legitimately to Int => Boolean. Just do

```
val x = Set(1,2,3)
println(x(2))
println(x(4))
```

So it proves Scala's Set is compatible in signature to Sett for this one operation.

Iterations in union are not needed. The type Sett holds reference to two sets.
If you go this:

```
  def union(s: Sett, t: Sett): Sett =
    (element: Int) => {
      println(element)
      s(element) || t(element)
    }

val u=union(Set(1,2,3),Set(4,5,6))
```

.. and then you call u(2) or whatever, the union def gets called with parameter element=2. Then the "s(element) || t(element)" is called. Set operations are of order 1 i.e. constant time. There is no need for iterations for s(element) operation because Sets are basically Maps with the value part not used.. only key is used, and keys are unique.
Martin Odersky really jumped the gun here and went too far. Should have been slower. Too many concepts covered.

Comment: There is no duck typing here. `scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]` inherits from `Int ⇒ Boolean`, and `Sett` is simply a type alias for `Int ⇒ Boolean`, so `Set` is a subclass of `Sett`, and it is always legal to cast an instance of a subclass type to an instance of a superclass type.

Comment: pedofurla maybe get more constructive and give your valuable inputs.. problem is ... is... u can't

Comment: Interesting you didn't ask "how you missed the point of the exercise." Which now, even if you ask, you won't get a answer from me.

Comment: Well, maybe if you ask nicely.

Comment: mr pedrofurla apologies for my remark. I am sure you see something more than what I can and acknowledge that you know something more than what I know. Pl share your knowledge. I will be very grateful Sir. Thanks.